# sql select throught join table

Tags: sql, join

Hy all,

I need a little help with writing a select...the problem is the following:

I have the following tables:

```
help
+----+-------+---------+
| id | title | content |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  | a     | acont   |
| 2  | b     | bcont   |
+----+-------+---------+

helptag
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | atag |
| 2  | btag |
+----+------+

helphelptag(join table)
+--------+-----------+
| helpid | helptagid |
+--------+-----------+
| 1      | 1         |
| 1      | 2         |
| 2      | 2         |
+--------+-----------+
```

I need to select those helps, whish has the ids i give.
So for example if i give tag_id 2, than both help 1 and 2
but if i give tag_id 1 and 2, than only help 1.

I've tried leftjoin, with the ids IN[tag_ids], but it gives back both helps if i give 1 and 2.

Comment: may be you should try putting some more data ! and tag relevant _RDBMS_ you are using !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to solve this using aggregation and `having` clause.  For your first question:

```
select helpid
from helphelptag
group by helpid
having sum(case when helptagid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

For the second, just add another condition:

```
having sum(case when helptagid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when helptagid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition counts the number of rows that match a given condition.